# send and recieve http request with python, need to send session cookies aswell

Tags: python, http, cookies, post, http-headers

I am testing my login function at my server (auto ip ban after x failed attempts). I found a simple python script that send http request like this:

```
import urllib, urllib2, re, os, sys, cookielib

def main():
    host = 'http://192.168.1.133/intro.php'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    username = 'admin'
    error =  '<p class="highlight">Login failed. Please try again.</p>'
    word_file = 'pass.txt'
    word_pos = 1

    file = open(word_file, 'r')
    word_list = file.read().split('\n')
    file.close

    for word in word_list:
        form = {'username': username, 'password': word}

        print 'Tring password: %s (%d/%d)' % (word, word_pos, len(word_list))
        word_pos = word_pos + 1

        data = urllib.urlencode(form)
        request = urllib2.Request(host, data, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

        size = response.headers.get("content-length")

        #print 'response %s' % (response.read())
        #print 'size: %s' % (size)

        if not re.search(error, response.read()):
            print 'Login Combination: [%s:%s]' % (username, word)
            save_combo = open('login comination.txt', 'w')
            save_combo.write(username + ':' + word)
            save_combo.close
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But my intro.php file look like this:

```
$a = session_id();
if ($a == '') session_start();
```

I have to send session cookies. This is a typical login request:

```
POST /intro.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.133
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.01 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.1.133/intro.php
Cookie: __utma=48024167.372656243.1297092510.1297169678.1297174274.6; __utmz=48024167.1297117542.3.2.utmcsr=search.genieo.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utmc=48024167; lang=en_US; PHPSESSID=7v8tt2ln0kaavo0ko7a7pklho6; __utmb=48024167.1.10.1297174274
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 39

username=yeyeye&pwd=123456&submit=Login
```

I want to make cookie variables so I can send cookies with every request, not just POST, Host, User-Agent that I send now. I just installed python so I am not quite sure how to use `cookielib`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
```

with

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    'Cookie': '__utma=48024167.372656243.1297092510.1297169678.1297174274.6...'
}
```